# Why does my disk run into problems/spike to 100% usage

Tags: windows

I currently have a "Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB SATA Disk Device" as my disk, and I often run into problems with it's usage spiking to 100% while all processes in task manager are showing 0.1mbps or less.  Last night when I was using a software to benchmark my PC, I noticed that the disk acted like this specifically on the 4kMixed benchmark.  After the disk was done with it's breakdown, the benchmarking program went onto a different benchmark on the disk, which cause my PC to bluescreen.  The dis was purchased less than 2 years ago, and I am unable to find any cause for this problem.  The disk has had this problem for the entirety of my ownership of it, and I would like to find a fix for it.

Other PC Specs (Just in case)

Processor - AMD FX6300 Six Core

RAM - 24G DDR3 RAM

Disk - Samsung SSD 860 EVO 1TB SATA

Network Adapter - Intel I211 Gigabit Network Connection

GPU - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

Edit:
It is probably not that big of a deal, but Task Manager tells me that my SSD is an HDD.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLbS0.png)

Edit 2:
My problem itself is that the disk has poor performance and will sometimes randomly spike to 100% usage while nothing is using it.  This causes me to not be able to interact with application windows, or to be able to open new apps.

Comment: Is the problem the blue screen? Or is the problem poor performance? It's hard to understand what your actual problem is.

Comment: Note that a disk can only do so much at a time. your issue isn't likely bandwidth, but the amount of time per interval that the device is in use (eg 100% of the measured second). hard disks tend to perform best when they are performing a single "long running" operation, where it can use maximum bandwidth. its analogous to copying several large files vs a large number of small files. by volume, the former performs much much better than the latter.

Comment: I can keep working along merrily with a VM or two starting in the background. Some slowness that goes away quickly. A good SSD should not struggle for occasional load especially for a period of weeks / months as I was lead to believe from the post.

Answer (score 0):

I have this SSD in my machine and it is quite smooth.

Run Admin Tools, Resource Monitor, and let it run for 15 to 30 minutes. Make sure the Disk line is open.  Then look to see what app / process is using the disk excessively.

[image]

Also run the manufacturer's Hardware Test app and /or Samsung Magician.  I use Magician and also my Lenovo Hardware Diagnostics.